# How to check touch on a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to know if there is a way to check if the user touched the bitmap, ofcourse im talking about an image without background, like a circle, a triangle and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: what bitmap? is it used by BitmapDrawable,  compound Drawable or ImageView?

Comment: so you want to check against Bitmap or some shape?

Comment: a bitmap with out any background, but if i have a picture of a circle or a triangle, i want to check if ONLY it touched the triangle

Comment: what is a bitmap with no background?

Comment: I mean, a bitmap of an image without background

Comment: ok,  seems i know what you mean: use Bitmap.getPixel method

Comment: lets say i have an image of a triangle without any background, how do I check that only the triangle has been touch and not the whole picture (including the empty area)

Comment: use Bitmap.getPixel method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> image without background, like a circle, a triangle and so on

then you should probably override View's `onTouch`, retrieve x and y from the touch event you got as parameter and compare it with the coords of the shape you drawn. The easiest way is to use `Rect.contains(int x, int y)`

Comment: But then it will check if the whole Rect contains it and not only the circle

Comment: you touch the screen and you want to know what you touched (which shape), am I wrong?

Comment: yes, but if i have a shape with like 8 edges, i want to know it if touch only the shape and not the rect that contains the shape

Comment: Every shape must have bounds within it is drawn. That bounds are you're rect

Comment: But i want to check if only the shape has been touched not the whole rect